# How to update via RequestContext

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to update a table by using  RequestContext.update()
The following code is working (jsf):

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%" columnClasses="treeColumn,tableColumn">
        <h:panelGroup id="treePanel">
            <p:tree id="tree" 
                    value="#{bean.root}" 
                    var="node" 
                    dynamic="true"
                    cache="true"
                    animate="true"
                    selectionMode="single"
                    selection="#{bean.selectedNode}"
                    rendered="#{bean.renderTree}"> 
                <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{bean.onNodeSelect}" update=":mainForm:treePanel,:mainForm:tablePanel"/>
                <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{bean.onNodeCollapse}"/>
                <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"  
                            collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" styleClass="tableTreeText"/>  
                </p:treeNode> 
                 <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"  
                             collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" styleClass="tableTreeText"/>  
                </p:treeNode> 
            </p:tree> 
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="tablePanel" styleClass="acqPanelTable">
            <p:dataTable id="acqDataTable"
                         widgetVar="acqTablehdsWidget"
                         var="acq"
                         value="#{bean.list}" 
                         rendered="#{bean.renderTable}"
                         filteredValue="#{bean.filteredList}"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorPosition="bottom"

     .....
     ....
     ...
     ..
     .
```

But not via the server side:

```
 RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
 requestContext.update(":mainForm:tablePanel");
 renderTable = true;
```

I don’t understand what is the different ?

Appreciate your help for any advice

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

Remove the leading colon.

```
requestContext.update("mainForm:tablePanel");
```

It's always resolved relative to `UIViewRoot`. The leading colon is only valid when you're currently sitting in an `UINamingContainer` component in the view.

Comment: For everyone interested the class RequestContext has been deprecated in PF 6.2 and totally replaced by class PrimeFaces in PF 7.0

Answer (score 6):

From PrimeFaces 7.0 and after the [class RequestContext](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.2/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html) have been replaced by the [class PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.2/org/primefaces/PrimeFaces.html) as indicated in the [migration guide](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide). Hence, in order to update a component you may call:

```
PrimeFaces.Ajax currentAjax = PrimeFaces.current().ajax();
currentAjax.update("myFormId:myDatatableId");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

**FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("formName:objectId");**

It works in primefaces 4.0

Comment: That is what using the requestContext behind the scenes does. It is a shortcut...

Answer (score -2):

```
RequestContext req = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
req.update("YourUIBlock");
```