# Primefaces asynchronous autocomplete: reality check

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm trying to make an autocomplete control to work with multiple sources of data, when they're having different access times. I googled a lot, but found only jquery or desktop solutions, which I was unable to adapt to jsf. My idea, basically, was to use completeMethod to spawn second thread and when it's done to refresh autocomplete list with more results.

This is my xhtml autocomplete component:

```
<p:autoComplete id="acSimple" value="#{testBean.txt1}" widgetVar="acSimple"
                completeMethod="#{testBean.completeText}" cache="true"/>
```

and completeMethod bean relevant lines:

```
private String oldQuery = "";
private List<String> result;

public List<String> completeText(String query) throws Exception {
    if (!oldQuery.equals(query)) {
        oldQuery = query;
        result = bpp.runFastQuery(query);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new SlowTask(query, result));
        thread.start();
        return result;
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}

class SlowTask implements Runnable {
    String str;

    SlowTask(String query, List<String> result) {
        str = query;
        this.result = result;
    }

    List<String> result;

    public void run() {
        try {
            List<String> r = bpp.runSlowQuery(str);
            result.addAll(r);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to run `PF('acSimple').search(txt1)` with when slower thread was finished, both from client side and both from bean, with `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":form1:acSimple");` but this didn't helped me either, it just updates the form without loading the new data.

If it possible at all to achieve what I want here?

Comment: My question is more specific, despite having same answers, also googling "async primefaces autocomplete" now will yield relevant result.

Comment: I think you are right It may provide additional help as removing `cache` attr affected the process as well.I will remove the flag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code may work refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17554922/1460591

I think your run method should be like this :

```
public void run() {
        try {
            List<String> r = bpp.runSlowQuery(str);
            result.addAll(r);
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form1:acSimple");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works in connections with `cache="false"`, thanks!